# Optimizing Regex for removing classes

Tags: javascript, regex

i have this function i use to remove classes from an element in javascript.

```
var reg = new RegExp(cls+'(\\s|$)');
this.el.className = this.el.className.replace(reg, '').replace(/\s+$/g, '');
```

say you have three classes on an element

```
show hide color
```

the first two get removed along with the whitespace after it, the third get's removed but since there is no whitespace after it, it leaves the space before it. The string then has an extra whitespace on the end. So i added a second replace function to get rid of that, but it is only used in one circumstance

**Question:** How do I get rid of that second replace function and have one regex do what I want. Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do, remove *all* classes (`element.className = '';`/`element.setAttribute('class','');`)? Or remove a specific class (`el.classList.remove('color');`)?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I am trying to remove a certain class (hence the cls variable in the regex). classList is unreliable so I am not working with it.

Comment: The regex is correct.The only reason can be because of a space before `show` or two spaces after `color`

Comment: @vks Yes it is working as I need it, but i'm trying to get rid of the need to call the replace function twice.

Comment: the space cannot be there if the strng is jsut `show hide color`.there is something else yu are missing

Comment: @vks The regex strips spaces after the occurance of the word. Say the string is `show hide color` and you strip `color` then you are left with `show hide `.

Comment: that won't work, for the string `show hide color` using that regex and removing `hide` will output `showcolor`

Comment: But why are you using regular expressions to remove a class-name, when there are DOM methods to do so?

Comment: classList is IE 10 and up. So that doesn't work for me, as stated already...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could handle all cases.

```
 #  (?:\s(?:show|hide|color)|(?:show|hide|color)\s|\b(?:show|hide|color)\b)

 (?:
      \s 
      (?: show | hide | color )
   |  
      (?: show | hide | color )
      \s 
   |  
      \b                          # Or ^
      (?: show | hide | color )
      \b                          # Or $
 )
```